# Enviar imagen SVG en Email

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, imagen, svg

Intenté enviar una imagen en código SVG para que un cliente de correo la interprete como HTML y sea visualizada.

El problema que solo en un cliente de correo veo la imagen, en la mayor parte no puede verse.

La forma como envío el código desde sql server es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE  @VAsunto varchar(100), @VHTML varchar(max), @BodyHTML varchar(max),@TblHTML VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @VTitulo VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @VAsunto = N'Graficas prueba: '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) 

select @VTitulo = N'Graficas'                                        

SELECT  @VHTML =N'
<html>
<head>
<title>Mi primer ejemplo en Google Charts</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Grafica" style="width: 800px; height: 600px">
    ---aqui el codigo svg

</div>

</body>
</html>
'

SELECT @VHTML = REPLACE(@VHTML,'$',char(39))

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQLCorreos',

@copy_recipients = 'aqui email' ,

@subject = @VAsunto,
@body = @VHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Hay alguna manera, en que pueda enviar ese código SVG para ser interpretado como imagen en Gmail, Outlook y el cliente de IOS?

Comment: Revisa este par de enlaces para que veas la compatibilidad entre clientes de correo electrónico: https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/ y https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/ Buena suerte :D

Comment: Si envía un html puedes usar en el src un base 64 <img src="data:image/png;base64,tu código b64

Comment: Me podrías indicar como es el base 64, nunca he trabajado con ello. Muchas muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Puedo agregar una respuesta con solo html y javascript?

Comment: Si por favor, te lo agradecería mucho.